# CKEDITOR dialog - open second tab on button click

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have CKEDITOR dialog with two tabs: 
- view one
- view two

Inside view one I have a button that should open view two if clicked by the user.

[image]

But I don't know how to do this. This is my CKEDITOR.dialog code:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('placeholder', function(editor) {
    var lang = editor.lang.placeholder,
        generalLabel = editor.lang.common.generalTab,
        validNameRegex = /^[^\[\]<>]+$/;

    return {
        title: 'some title',
        minWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 150,
        contents: [{
            id: 'initial-view',
            label: 'view one',
            title: generalLabel,
            elements: [{
                id: 'name-one',
                style: 'width: 100%;',
                type: 'html',
                html: 'Organizational units'
            }, {
                type: 'button',
                id: 'buttonId',
                label: 'Click me',
                title: 'My title',
                setup: function(widget) {

                    },
                onClick: function(widget) {
                    // this = CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.button
                    My code should go here........?
                }
            }]
        }, {
            id: 'organizational-unit-view',
            label: 'view two',
            title: generalLabel,
            elements: [
                // Dialog window UI elements.
                {
                    id: 'list-of-vars',
                    style: 'width: 100%;',
                    type: 'html',
                    html: 'second view --- html goes here',
                    label: lang.name,
                    setup: function(widget) {
                        this.setValue(widget.data.name);
                    },
                    commit: function(widget) {
                        widget.setData('name', this.getValue());
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    };
});
```

My question is how should I handle that button click?  What method should I use? Basically how to open view two?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. On click event is should use getDialog():

```
 this.getDialog().selectPage('your-content-id);
```

Like this:

```
onClick: function(widget) {
    this.getDialog().selectPage('organizational-unit-view');
}
```